# insert and update in one submit button but different table of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table filled with some data and there is one column called `status_antrian` (set default by 1 in 'data_pasien' table of mysql).

In html, this column `status_antrian` linked with href to the form.

So, after click the submit button and insert form into `inputrm` table of mysql, I want to update `status_antrian` in `data_pasien` into 0 (which disable it from table).

I already did the insert and updates code, but `status_antrian` didnt change into 0.

how can I resolve this?

the controller

```
function save_data_input_rm()
{
    $insert = array();

    $insert['waktu']                = $_POST['waktu'];
    $insert['no_registrasi']        = $_POST['no_registrasi'];
    $insert['no_rm']                = $_POST['no_rm'];
    $insert['nama_pemilik']         = $_POST['nama_pemilik'];
    $insert['nama_hewan']           = $_POST['nama_hewan'];
    $insert['diagnosis']            = $_POST['diagnosis'];
    $insert['signalemen_ttl']       = $_POST['signalemen_ttl'];
    $insert['signalemen_kelamin']   = $_POST['signalemen_kelamin'];
    $insert['berat_badan']          = $_POST['berat_badan'];
    $insert['username']             = $_POST['username'];
    $insert['nama_mahasiswa']       = $_POST['nama_mahasiswa'];

    $this->rekammedis_model->insert_users_checkbox_inap($insert);

    $id_antrian = $_GET['id'];
    $this->rekammedis_model->disable_antrian($id_antrian);

    redirect('daftar_rm');
}
```

the model

```
function insert_users_checkbox_inap($insert)
{
    $data = array(
            'waktu'                 => $insert['waktu'],
            'no_registrasi'         => $insert['no_registrasi'],
            'no_rm'                 => $insert['no_rm'],
            'nama_pemilik'          => $insert['nama_pemilik'],
            'nama_hewan'            => $insert['nama_hewan'],
            'diagnosis'             => $insert['diagnosis'],
            'signalemen_ttl'        => $insert['signalemen_ttl'],
            'signalemen_kelamin'    => $insert['signalemen_kelamin'],
            'berat_badan'           => $insert['berat_badan'],
            'username'              => $insert['username'],
            'nama_mahasiswa'        => $insert['nama_mahasiswa']
        );

    $query = $this->db->insert('inputrminap', $data); 
}

function disable_antrian($id_antrian)
{
    $data = array(
        'status_antrian' => 0 //1 means it's true
    );
    $id_antrian = $_GET['id'];
    $this->db->where('id', $id_antrian)->update('data_pasien', $data); 
    return true;
}
```

the html table

```
  <table id="tabel-pas" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive wrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Waktu</th>
      <th>No. Registrasi</th>
      <th>No. Rekam Medis</th>
      <th>Nama Pemilik</th>
      <th>Nama Hewan</th>                                         
      <th>Aksi</th>           
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php
      $no = 1;
      foreach($datapas_aktif as $row){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$row->waktu."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->no_registrasi."</td>";     
      echo "<td>".$row->no_rm."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->nama_pemilik."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row->nama_hewan."</td>";
      echo "<td>";

        echo '<a href="linktoinputrm?id='.$row->id.'">Dalam Antrian</a>';

      echo"</td>";
      echo"</tr>";$no++;
      }            
    ?>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You pass `$_GET['id']` as a parameter to `disable_antrian($id_antrian)` so why are you doing a `$id_antrian = $_GET['id'];` again inside that function.

Comment: I  dont see you checking that `$_GET['id']` actually exists before attempting to use its value????

Comment: All your other values come in `$_POST` so do we assume you pressed a SUBMIT button? If so the `id` on the `<a href="xxx?id=1"...` will not be passed to the script in `$_GET` You will need to add the `id` as a `hidden` fields within your `<form>`

Comment: When you call `insert_users_checkbox_inap($insert)` you load an array called `$insert` Inside the function you unload that array into an EXACT Duplicate of the parameter array. Are you paid by the CPU cycles your code uses?????

Comment: To give a proper answer we would need to see your HTML code as well

Comment: i already edited the question sir @RiggsFolly

Comment: I dont see a `<form>` so where are you getting the `$_POST` data from